# Using HTML5 for client-side form validation

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I want to use HTML5 attributes like type, pattern, required, minlength etc. to validate my web form as client-side validation. And I'm not using JavaScript for the same purpose. And of course, for the server-side validation I'm going to use PHP.

What kind of security issues, if any, will it create for my web form ( as I'm not using JavaScript validation) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only issue is that these attributes can be ignored by some browsers. And javascript will work everywhere if enabled.

Comment: Then should I use HTML5 and JavaScript both? @user4035

Comment: @user3724591 Well, if you use javascript, then there will no need for HTML 5 validation. But if you use HTML 5, javascript will protect your code in the browsers, that don't support some of HTML special attributes.

Comment: @user3724591, you should use double validation of your data. Because many times people disable JavaScript in their browsers. Then only server side validation with php will save you. So, you must validate your data with HTML5 attributes(as much it's possible with them)because it's easy with it, then you validate it with JavaScript also and don't forget to validate it with php as well. Now, our data is validate for all types of general consequences.

Comment: Also, HTML5 validation is better for accessibility http://www.deque.com/blog/accessible-client-side-form-validation-html5/

Comment: @RKV He said in his question: "And of course, for the server-side validation I'm going to use PHP."

Answer (score 1):

The html5 validation is only for a better user experience, and not for security. You already triggered that by using server side validation, using PHP.

For your server validation design, it makes no difference whether you use HTML5 validation or not.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is a list of top 10 Website Security issues.


Out of which HTML5 attributes can handle only 1st one. While php can take care of 2,3,4,5,7 and 10.


Also keep in mind, as user4035 mentioned that HTML5 attributes are not supported by old browsers.

You should use double validation of your data. Because many times people disable JavaScript in their browsers. Then only server side validation with php will save you. So, you must validate your data with HTML5 attributes(as much it's possible with them)because it's easy with it, then you validate it with JavaScript also and don't forget to validate it with php as well. Now, our data is validate for all types of general consequences.



1.
Validation of input and output data :

All data used by the website (from users, other servers, other websites 
and internal systems) must be validated for type (e.g. numeric, date, 
string), length (e.g. 200 characters maximum, or a 
positive integer) and 
syntax (e.g. product codes begin with 2 letters and are followed by 5 
digits) and business rules (e.g. televisions can only cost between £100 and 
£2000, an order can contain at most 20 items, daily
 credit limit must not 
be exceeded).  All data written as output (displayed) needs to be safe to 
view in a browser, email client or other software and the integrity of any 
data that is returned must be checked.  Utilising A
synchronous JavaScript 
and XML (AJAX) or Adobe Flex increase complexity and the possible attack 
vectors. 


2.
Direct data access (and theft) :

If data exists, it can potentially be viewed or extracted.  Avoid storing 
data  that  you  do  not  need  on  the  website  and  its  database(s)  –  for 
example some data relating to payment cards should 
never be stored.
Poorly developed systems may allow access to data through SQL injection 
       Top 10 
Website security issues 
2
compromises,  insufficient  input  and  output  data  validation  (see  No  1 
above) or poor system security. 


3.
Data poisoning :

If user’s can amend or delete data inappropriately 
and this is then used to 
update your internal systems, business information 
is being lost.  This can 
be hard to detect and it is important that the business rules are examined 
and  enforced  to  validate  data  changes  to  ensure  poisoning  is  not 
occurring.  If poisoning is not detected until well
 after it has occurred, it 
may be impossible to recover the original data. 


4.
Malicious file execution :

Uploaded files or other data feeds may not be what 
they seem.  Never 
allow user-supplied input to be used in any file na
me or path (e.g. URLs or 
file  system  references).    Uploaded  files  may  also  contain  a  malicious 
payload so should not be stored in web accessible locations. 


5.
Authentication and session management :

Websites rely on identifying users to provide access permissions to data 
and functions.  If authentication (verification of 
identity, registration and 
logging in), authorisation (granting access rights)
 and session management 
(keeping track of the identity of a logged in user 
while they browse a 
website) can be circumvented or altered, a user could access resources 
they are not allowed to.  Beware especially of how password reminders, 
remember-me, change password, log out and updating 
account details are 
handled, how session tokens are used and always have login forms on 
dedicated and encrypted (SSL) pages. 


6.
System architecture and configuration :

The information system architecture model should address the sensitivity 
of data identified during the requirements and specification phase of a 
website project.  This may entail having separate web, application and 
database servers or involve clustering, load balancing or virtualisation.
Additional  security  issues  can  be  created  through  t
he  way  the  live 
environment is configured.  Sufficient and safe logging, monitoring and 
alerting facilities need to be built in to allow audit. 
       Top 10 
Website security issues 
3


7.
Phishing :

Phishing, where users are conned into believing some other entity is or 
belongs to your own organisation (email messages and websites are the 
most common combination), is best tackled through user education but 
the  way  the  website  is  designed,  its  architecture  and  how  it 
communicates with users can reduce the risk. 


8.
Denial of service :

Whilst malicious users might try to swamp the web server with a vast 
number of requests or actions that degrade its performance (filling up 
logs, uploading large files, undertaking tasks that
 require a lot of memory 
repeatedly)  denial  of  service  attacks  include  locking  out  valid  user 
accounts or be caused by coding problems (e.g. memory leaks, resources 
not being released). 


9.
System information leakage :

Web  servers,  errors,  staff,  partner  organisations, 
search  engines  and 
rubbish can all be the source of important information about your website 
– its technologies, business logic and security met
hods.  An attacker can 
use such information to their advantage so it is important to avoid system 
information leakage as far as possible. 


10.
Error handling:

 
Exceptions  such  as  user  data  validation  messages,  missing  pages  and 
server errors should be handled by the code so that
 a custom page is 
displayed that does not provide any system information to the user (see 
No  9  above).    Logging  and  alerting  of  unusual  conditions  should  be 
enabled and these should allow subsequent audit. 


Reference: [Click Here](https://www.watsonhall.uk/resources/downloads/top10-website-security-issues.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Client side validation is used purely for speeding things up - it doesn't improve security in any way. Client side validation allows the user to see live if their input will be accepted or not by the server without submitting the form. It is quite user friendly.

Server side validation is the important one, however, as people can always send arbitrary data to your server, completely ignoring the HTML/Javascript constraints. In the end it's just an HTTP request, so anyone can fake it. But no one can bypass the server that is in between the user and the database, so all validation must happen there.